# Transfer Session & Cookies generated by PHP Curl into browser

Tags: php, curl, browser

My client says he wants to login to a website within his website. That part is fine. I used CURL to login remotely. But then he wants me to redirect him to that website. With the page prelogged in. Any suggestions?

My code is simple

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// get headers too with this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

it saves the cookies in cookie.txt file. How can I just make him login.

consider a just like he doesn't want to go to Facebook page to login. He wants to login to his facebook account using input fields within his own website. Once message appears, he just opens facebook.com and it appears already logged in.